# Summary stats a variable for each unique variable within a condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a longitudinal spreadsheet that contains different growth variables for many individuals.  At the moment my R code looks like this:

```
D5<-ifelse(growth$agyr == 5, growth$R.2ND.DIG.AVERAGE,NA)
```

Since it is longitudinal, I have the same measurement for each individual at multiples ages, thus the variable agyr.  In this example it is taking all kids who have a finger measurement at age 5.

What I would like to do is do that for all ages so that I don't have to define an object every time, so I can essentially run some summary stats on finger length for any given agyr.  Surely this is possible, but I am still a beginner at R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tapply()` is your friend here. For the mean for example:

```
with(growth,
     tapply(R.2ND.DIG.AVERAGE,agyr,mean)
)
```

See also `?tapply` and some good introduction book on R. And also `?with`, a function that can really make your code a lot more readible.

If you have multiple levels you want to average over, you can give `tapply()` a list of factors. Say `gender` is a variable as well (a factor!), you can do eg:

```
with(growth,
     tapply(R.2ND.DIG.AVERAGE,list(agyr,gender),mean)
)
```

`tapply()` returns an array-like structure (a vector, matrix or multidimensional array, depending on the number of categorizing factors). If you want your results in a data frame and/or summarize multiple variables at once, look at `?aggregate`, eg:

```
thevars <- c("R.2ND.DIG.AVERAGE","VAR2","MOREVAR")
aggregate(growth[thevars],by=list(agyr,gender), FUN="mean")
```

or using the formula interface:

```
aggregate(cbind(R.2ND.DIG.AVERAGE,VAR2,MOREVAR) ~ agyr + gender, 
         data=growth, FUN = "mean")
```

Make sure you check the help files as well. Both `tapply()` and `aggregate()` are quite powerful and have plenty other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks.  Sorry, I didn't put this in my original question but is there a way to tease out sex for each year if I have another variable that has sex coded?

Comment: Added some extra information for you. Check the help files I refer to as well, they're really helpful and contain more examples.